# How to Nest List Views in NativeScript

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm trying to display a list of items within a list of items.  Basically it's a card game, where each suit is being repeated, and then each card for each suit is being repeated.

```html
<StackLayout margin="10 0 60 0" padding="0 0">
    <ListView class="list-group" [items]="hand" (itemTap)="onItemTap($event)"
        (itemLoading)="onItemLoading($event)" backgroundColor="#26252A"
        style="height:100%">
        <ng-template let-suit="item">
            <FlexboxLayout flexDirection="row">
                <ScrollView orientation="horizontal">
                        <StackLayout height="100" orientation="horizontal" margin="2.5, 15">
                            <ListView class="list-group" [items]="suit.cards">
                                <ng-template let-card="item">
                                    <Label [text]="card" class="card"></Label>
                                </ng-template>
                        </ListView>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ScrollView>
            </FlexboxLayout>
        </ng-template>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

And this is what my "hand" looks like:

```ts
hand: { suit: Suit, fontColor: Color, cards: string[] }[] = [
    { suit: "Red", fontColor: new Color("red"), cards: ["14", "13"] },
    { suit: "Green", fontColor: new Color("green"), cards: ["14", "13", "12", "9"] },
    { suit: "Yellow", fontColor: new Color("yellow"), cards: ["14", "13", "10", "9"] },
    { suit: "Black", fontColor: new Color("black"), cards: ["14", "13", "9"] }
];
```

When I run it though, I'm only getting the very first card in each suit to be displayed.

You can check it out at the playground here:

https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=XfogFt&v=3

(I'm new to both NaitiveScript and Angular, so I may be missing something simple)

Comment: Which platform you're testing it on? Android or iOS

Comment: @SalehMahmood Android, but ideally, it shouldn't matter.

Comment: ERROR: ERROR ReferenceError: Can't find variable: MyDataSource?Looks like Playground sample is not complete.

Comment: @NarendraMongiya it doesn't error on my Nexus 6p (Android 8.1.0, Preview app 1.18.0, Runtime 5.1.0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> EDIT: It is not advisable to use nested listview as  this would break
> the recycling and virtualization for cells that are containing a
> nested listview

You don't need a scrollview inside the ng-template, if you just remove it, it will show your all the items in each row of parent list.

```html
<ListView class="list-group" [items]="hand" (itemTap)="onItemTap($event)"
          (itemLoading)="onItemLoading($event)" backgroundColor="#26252A"
          style="height:100%">
    <ng-template let-suit="item">
        <FlexboxLayout flexDirection="row">
            <!-- <ScrollView orientation="horizontal"> -->
                    <StackLayout height="100" orientation="horizontal" margin="2.5, 15">
                        <ListView class="list-group" [items]="suit.cards">
                            <ng-template let-card="item">
                                <Label [text]="card" class="card"></Label>
                            </ng-template>
                    </ListView>
                </StackLayout>
            <!-- </ScrollView> -->
            <Label text="Label"></Label>
        </FlexboxLayout>
    </ng-template>
</ListView>
```

I have updated the playground [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=XfogFt&v=4). You can also use the itemHeight and itemWidth properties here for size tuning.

P.S. The itemHeight and itemWidth properties are iOS specific. If not used, items are sized dynamically depending on the data coming from the source.

Comment: I'm going to have more cards than will fit in the screen, so I want to be able to scroll each suit horizontal as well.  Does that still work if I remove the scroll view?

Comment: Yes, Scroll is working as listview has it's own scroll.

Comment: And if you want horizontal scroll as well, you can use Layout for child listview. http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/Angular/ListView/item-layouts

Comment: Hmm... That didn't work for me.  Nothing apparently has changed.

Comment: It's workinng for me for ios but is it is not recommended due to performance reason. https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/92

Comment: As you are using Angular, you can use FlexBoxLayout in ng-template with *ngFor for Card Labels

Answer (score 1):

As @Narendra mentioned it's not recommended to use nested list views or ngFor inside template.

I guess [nativescript-accordion](https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-accordion) plugin will suit your needs, it basically supports the data structure you are looking for - List Item -> List of Items (Suit -> Cards). If you like to show the items expanded upon loading, all you have to do is, populate the selectedIndexes with all indexes. There is [one issue](https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-accordion/issues/54) with latest version of the plugin, which can be still handled with a simple math.

[Preventing collapse](https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-accordion/issues/55) upon tap is still an open feature request, but possible to achieve with an override. But as far I know, this plugin could be the only viable solution for nested list views.